# UICollectionView two cells with same views. Second cell shows nothing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What would cause this behaviour? I have a collectionview with two cells. The two cells should have the same views but different text content. Nothing shows up in the second cell. Am I doing something wrong in "cellforrowat"? What am I missing?

[image: Dragon]
[image: DragonExtra]

```
class UpgradeController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate{


    let numMonths = ["1","6","12"]
    let months = ["month","months","months"]
    let prices = ["$19.99","$79.99","$99.99"]
    let pricePerMonth = ["","($13.33 per month)","($8.33 per month)"]
    let pricesExtra = ["$29.99","119.99","149.99"]
    let pricePerMonthExtra = ["","$19.99 per month","$12.49 per month"]



    var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    var scrollView:UIScrollView!

    let cellId = "cellId"
    let cellId2 = "cellId2"


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupViews()


    }


    func setupViews(){
        let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let navBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
        let tabBarheight: CGFloat = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height
        let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
        let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height


        //view.setGradientBackgroundColor(colorOne: UIColor(rgb:0x000000), colorTwo: UIColor(rgb:0x056644))
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        setupCollectionView()
        setupMenuBar()


        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear //.orange
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:50,width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height)


        if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal    //= .horizontal
        }
        scrollView.addSubview(self.collectionView)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
```

**Collection view setup** :

```
    func setupCollectionView(){

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 120, right: 0)
        //layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth / 3, height: screenWidth / 3)
        //layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView?.register(DragonCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)


        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }


    let titles = ["Dragon", "DragonExtra"]

    lazy var menuBar: MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        mb.backgroundColor = .red
        mb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mb.names = ["Dragon", "DragonExtra"]
        mb.upgradeController = self

        return mb
    }()

    private func setupMenuBar(){

        menuBar.setupHorizontalBar()
        //menuBar.multiplier = CGFloat(1/8.0)
        view.addSubview(menuBar) //view.addSubview(menuBar)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(\(view.frame.width*CGFloat(menuBar.names.count)/4.0))]", views: menuBar)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(50)]|", views: menuBar)
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[v1]-(<=1)-[v0]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0":menuBar,"v1":self.view])) //center horizontally
    }

    func scrollToMenuIndex(menuIndex:Int){
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: menuIndex, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: [], animated: true)

        //setTitleForIndex(index:menuIndex)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        //menuBar.horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.x/2 + view.frame.width/8.0
        menuBar.horizontalBarLeftAnchorConstraint?.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.x/CGFloat(titles.count*2)
    }


    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

        let index = targetContentOffset.pointee.x / view.frame.width
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: Int(index), section: 0)
        menuBar.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
        //setTitleForIndex(index:Int(index))
    }


    private func setTitleForIndex(index:Int){
        /*
         if let titleLabel = navigationItem.titleView as? UILabel{
         titleLabel.text = titles[Int(index)]
         }
         */
    }
```

**Collection view delegate methods** :

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 2
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
  {

      print(indexPath.item)
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DragonCell
      switch indexPath.item{
        case 0:
          cell.numMonths = numMonths
          cell.months = months
          cell.prices = prices
          cell.pricePerMonth = pricePerMonth
          cell.backgroundColor = .blue

          return cell
        case 1:
          cell.numMonths = numMonths
          cell.months = months
          cell.prices = pricesExtra
          cell.pricePerMonth = pricePerMonthExtra
          cell.backgroundColor = .red

          return cell

        default:
          let cell = UICollectionViewCell() //collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
          return cell
      }

  }



  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      return CGSize(width:view.frame.width,height:view.frame.height)
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code you are wanting to reuse the same collection view but simply change content ?

So why not have a condition based on what menu bar item is selected?

like so...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    print(indexPath.item)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DragonCell

    //Not exactly sure if this is correct for what you have written 
//for your code. But the idea is take the index that is shown or active //from your menu bar. 
//You have used a switch statement which used the collection view //index. not the menubar index
    if menuBar.index == 0 {
        cell.numMonths = numMonths
        cell.months = months
        cell.prices = prices
        cell.pricePerMonth = pricePerMonth
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue

        return cell
    } else {
        cell.numMonths = numMonths
        cell.months = months
        cell.prices = pricesExtra
        cell.pricePerMonth = pricePerMonthExtra
        cell.backgroundColor = .red

        return cell
    }
    //switch indexPath.item{
      //case 0:
        //cell.numMonths = numMonths
        //cell.months = months
        //cell.prices = prices
        //cell.pricePerMonth = pricePerMonth
        //cell.backgroundColor = .blue

        //return cell
      //case 1:
        //cell.numMonths = numMonths
        //cell.months = months
        //cell.prices = pricesExtra
        //cell.pricePerMonth = pricePerMonthExtra
        //cell.backgroundColor = .red

        //return cell

      //default:
        //let cell = UICollectionViewCell() //collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}
```

It looks like in your switch statement you are using the indexPath of the Collectionview. But dont you want to show content based on the index path of the menu bar selected?

However, I would go through an entirely different approach and create a SECOND collection view for that other view.

Comment: hey. This is a collectionview with two custom cells lined up horizontally. Each cell is as wide as the screen. Each cell then has a collectionview ( so it's basically collectionviews inside the cells of another collectionview). i want to reuse the same collection view for the second cell. Did you mean that i should create a separate custom collectionview cell called "DragonExtra"? and just copy and paste the code i used in DragonCell into DragonCellExtra? If so, I tried that already

Comment: @caa5042 That would make your life a lot easier if you did that. The approach your taking is kinda complicated to follow. However,  your problem looks like its the switch statement that is using the indexPath of the collectionview. the other cell is not established. By nesting a collection view inside a collection view.. this bad practice can lead to issues. As well as not being able to access the correct collection view

Comment: Yeah I used that approach (one class for dragon and a separate one for dragonextra) but the exact same problem. So nesting a collectionview in another is bad practice?  Actually this is THREE collection views nested. So i'm assuming that's even worse?. It's two collectionview cells, then each cell has a collectionview (the three horizontal square cells you see)  with a header that i created with "viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind" function.....  the header in turn has another collectionview(the carousel).  i have an idea for a workaround

Comment: @caa5042  yes very bad practice ! You need to create two separate collection views ( or if you prefer you can use one and have two static cells ) inside the collection view use a UIView as the content view. Inside the content view is where you have all your other labels and buttons and so on. I will post edited answer shortly